# Getting access token for an api protected by B2C, using custom policies

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I have an api that is protected using ADB2C authentication. I need to call this api via custom policies. I followed the documentation [enter link description here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/secure-rest-api) and have added the two technical profiles as validation technical profile of a self asserted profile.

I am getting an access token returned by the below technical profile :

```
<TechnicalProfile Id="SecureREST-AccessToken">
      <DisplayName></DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.RestfulProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
      <Metadata>
        <Item Key="ServiceUrl">https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant id here}/oauth2/v2.0/token</Item>
        <Item Key="AuthenticationType">Basic</Item>
        <Item Key="SendClaimsIn">Form</Item>
      </Metadata>
      <CryptographicKeys>
        <Key Id="BasicAuthenticationUsername" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_SecureRESTClientId" />
        <Key Id="BasicAuthenticationPassword" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_SecureRESTClientSecret" />
      </CryptographicKeys>
      <InputClaims>
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="grant_type" DefaultValue="client_credentials" />
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="scope" DefaultValue="{app id uri for protected resource}/.default" />
      </InputClaims>
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="bearerToken" PartnerClaimType="access_token" />
      </OutputClaims>
      <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-Noop" />
    </TechnicalProfile>
```

And then making the rest api call using below profile :

```
<TechnicalProfile Id="UserMigrationViaLegacyIdp">
                <DisplayName>REST API call to communicate with Legacy IdP</DisplayName>
                <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.RestfulProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
                <Metadata>
                    <Item Key="ServiceUrl">
         
          https://99a0a14a6402.ngrok.io/api/Identity/SignUpAsync
        </Item>
                    <Item Key="AuthenticationType">Bearer</Item>
                    <Item Key="SendClaimsIn">Header</Item>
                    <Item Key="AllowInsecureAuthInProduction">false</Item>
        <Item Key="UseClaimAsBearerToken">bearerToken</Item>


      </Metadata>
                <InputClaims>
                    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="bearerToken"/>
      </InputClaims>
                <OutputClaims>
                    
                    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="phonePresent"/>

                </OutputClaims>
                <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-Noop" />
            </TechnicalProfile>
```

However, scopes are missing from the returned access token, hence token validation is failing on the api.

Is my call to get access token missing anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the client credentials grant flow, the API permissions must be created as *roles* (see [How to: Add app roles to your application and receive them in the token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-add-app-roles-in-azure-ad-apps)) and then granted admin consent (see [Admin consent button](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-configure-app-access-web-apis#admin-consent-button)).

As result, the bearer token contains the `roles` claim, rather than the `scp` claim.

The API application checks access using this `roles` claim (see [Verify app roles in APIs called by daemon apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-protected-web-api-verification-scope-app-roles#verify-app-roles-in-apis-called-by-daemon-apps)).